# Github commit: Fatal: unable to process path: d_Visibility_Hidded@2x.png.meta

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, github

```
error: lstat("MMRA/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.animation@4.2.4/Editor/Assets/SkinningModule/Icons/Selected/d_Visibility_Hidded@2x.png.meta"): Filename too long
fatal: Unable to process path MMRA/Library/PackageCache/com.unity.2d.animation@4.2.4/Editor/Assets/SkinningModule/Icons/Selected/d_Visibility_Hidded@2x.png.meta
```

Trying to commit a Unity2D project and Github doesn't see to like these filetypes. It's a file for a blank Unity project so not a file I made (meaning I probably shouldn't just remove it).

I also tried `git config --system core.longpaths true` and that didn't fix either error, which is why I believe the second error is the true problem rather than a long filename (which isn't even that long).

I've seen similar posts about a similar error, but most involve "Permission denied" which this doesn't, or they're about other filetypes where the solution is "just delete it" which I feel like I shouldn't do in this case.

Comment: What OS are you on? I only remember long file names being a problem in Windows, but not in git itself.

Comment: Also, why are you having stuff in your Library path in version control? Shouldn't be necessary normally. Especially the Package Cache is not something to add to version control.

Comment: Windows 10. Also I'm not sure about the libraries. I just made a unity project in the repo folder. Is there a better way to do it?

It's for a class. We were given a .gitignore file and it does seem to ignore that folder, but I'm unsure why it doesn't actually ignore it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not add your project's `Library` folder to version control at all.

A typical .gitignore file for a Unity project should at least have these entries:

```
[Ll]ibrary/
[Ll]ogs/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
```

Comment: Being for a class, the professor gave us a .gitignore file to use. It does contain those lines, among others. But it doesn't seem to apply for some reason. It's in the repo's root folder so I'm unsure what the problem here is.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this:

```
[Ll]ibrary/
[Ll]ogs/
[Tt]emp/
[Oo]bj/
```

for this:

```
*/[Ll]ibrary/
*/[Ll]ogs/
*/[Tt]emp/
*/[Oo]bj/
```

worked for me. I think that's the case if those folders are inside another folder (they're not at the the folder as .gitignore)